# How should I describe this?

Tags: meaning

[image]
This is definitely described as '2 triangles.'

[image]
I don't know how to describe this. Should I describe it as '1 square with a slash'? I think 'two triangles' is inappropriate.

Comment: A square with a diagonal line across it.

Comment: Indeed, 'two triangles' is wrong?

Comment: It's not a question about English language learning.

Comment: But there's no proper forum ㅠㅠㅠ

Comment: Calling it 'two triangles' says nothing about their position relative to one another. But this is really a geometry question.

Comment: @Kate Bunting I don't understand

Comment: 'Two triangles' could equally well  be ΔΔ.